# Parsing dynamic data in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to parse dynamic data in Dart.

What I know: value is definitely int or double, but can be represented like String, int or double. 
For example, "10.0", 10, 10.0

So in order to convert this to double I have to perform the following code:

```
double parsed = double.parse(value.toString());
```

It looks logical. First of all I make sure value is a String, secondly I parse it. But my concern it isn't quite intuitive. Is there easier approaches?

Answer (score 0):

For the particular set of representations you have here, I'd probably go with parsing it as JSON:

```
var jsonValue = json.parse(value); // jsonValue is int, double or String
if (jsonValue is String) jsonValue = double.parse(jsonValue); // Is int or double
double parse = jsonValue.toDouble(); // Only double.
```

More generally, you would have to figure out which format the string is in yourself, and then use an appropriate approach for each. You can use RegExps for that:

```
var doubleFormat = RegExp(r'^"?([\d.]+)"?$');
var match = doubleFormat.firstMatch(value);
if (match == null) throw FormatException("Invalid format!", value);
var parsed = double.parse(match[1]);
```

You have to tailor the regular expression to the formats you expect to parse. If the formats may contain whitespace, you need to account for that too.